# Why my data not saved to CoreData after restart application?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I have this `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // create API request
    VKRequest * newsRequest = [VKApi requestWithMethod: @"newsfeed.get"
                                         andParameters: @{@"filters":@"post"}
                                         andHttpMethod: @"GET"];
    // execute request
    [newsRequest executeWithResultBlock:^(VKResponse *response) {

        NSArray *items = response.json[@"items"]; // json to array
        for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
            Post *post = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Post"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            [post setSource_id: item[@"source_id"]];
            [post setText: item[@"text"]];
            [post setDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: [item[@"date"] intValue] ] ];
            [post setType: item[@"type"]];
            [post setNumber_of_comments: @( [item[@"comments"][@"count"] intValue] ) ];
            [post setNumber_of_likes: @( [item[@"likes"][@"count"] intValue] ) ];
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save: &error]) { // save data
                NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
        // request to coredata here
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Post"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:description];
        NSError *requestError = nil;
        NSArray *resultArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: request
                                                                        error: &requestError];
        NSLog(@"data: %@ /n", resultArray);

    } errorBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];

}
```

After first start all seems ok (i see all my data in console), but if i restart app, i see 50 (number of posts i get) lines look like this:

```
    "<Post: 0x8dbe110> (entity: Post; id: 0x8dac000 <x-coredata://EDD8C9C8-35E5-4C26-B6D2-8A9C00B077CF/Post/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Post: 0x8dbe170> (entity: Post; id: 0x8dacde0 <x-coredata://EDD8C9C8-35E5-4C26-B6D2-8A9C00B077CF/Post/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Post: 0x8dbe1c0> (entity: Post; id: 0x8dad970 <x-coredata://EDD8C9C8-35E5-4C26-B6D2-8A9C00B077CF/Post/p3> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Post: 0x8dbe210> (entity: Post; id: 0x8dad980 <x-coredata://EDD8C9C8-35E5-4C26-B6D2-8A9C00B077CF/Post/p4> ; data: <fault>)",
    .........
    .........
```

And after this i have my data. Obiusly this 50 objects comes from previous start, but why i see it like `<fault>`?

After 5 starts, console displays 200 `<fault>` data and then 50 normal lines.

Normal data looks like this:

```
"<Post: 0x8d93050> (entity: Post; id: 0x8d94a70 <x-coredata://EDD8C9C8-35E5-4C26-B6D2-8A9C00B077CF/Post/p405> ; data: {\n    attachments = nil;\n    date = \"2014-06-05 23:39:23 +0000\";\n    \"number_of_comments\" = 0;\n    \"number_of_likes\" = 8;\n    source = nil;\n    \"source_id\" = \"-30509296\";\n    text = \"PROMO GALLERY Open Your Mind\";\n    type = post;\n})",
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fault in Core Data is not a fault as in failure, it is just Apple's way of reducing the memory usage of your application. You can turn off the property by calling:

```
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```